# Printf output on godbolt using xtensa compiler?

Tags: c++, printf, c++20, xtensa, godbolt

Is there some way to produce output in godbolt for the Xtensa compiler?

[This](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:6),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++printf(%22Hello+World!!%22)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:66.07329842931937,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:esp32g2020r1,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Xtensa+ESP32+gcc+8.2.0+(2020r1)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+Xtensa+ESP32+gcc+8.2.0+(2020r1)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:33.92670157068063,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

generates an asm call to printf, but nothing is displayed.

Comment: In the source code tab click `Add New...` then `Execution Only`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That switches me back to x86 gcc :/ Anyhow, I can't reselect the xtensa compiler. Was it removed just now?

Comment: It's possible execution isn't supported for that target. *shrug*

Comment: The compiler explorer doesn't have the capabilities to run on all platforms that there are compilers for. If you donate an ESP32 system (or more) and figure out a way to connect it to the cloud system that runs the compiler explorer, then you're more than welcome to add that support. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would happily donate, if esp gets integrated. Where can I do so?